# Can't invoke the component's method

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-component

Using an EventBus on my Laravel-Vuejs project. I'm emitting an items-updated event from `ItemCreate` component after the successful `Item` creation. On the same page I'm using `ItemList` component which shows a list of created `Items`

Here is the codes:

### app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
window.EventBus = new Vue();

Vue.component('item-list', 
  require('./components/entities/item/ItemList'));
Vue.component('item-create', 
  require('./components/entities/item/ItemCreate'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

### ItemCreate.vue Component

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            itemName: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {sendItemData: function () {
            axios.post('/dashboard/item', {
                name: this.itemName
            })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 201) {
                        toastr.success('Item created successfully!', {timeout: 2000});
                        EventBus.$emit('items-updated');
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    toastr.error(error, 'Ooops! Something went wrong!');
                })
        }
    }
}
```

### ItemList.vue Component

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            items: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getItems: function () {
            axios.get('/dashboard/items')
                .then(response => {
                    this.items = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    toastr.error(error, 'Ooops! Something went wrong!');
                })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getItems();
        EventBus.$on('items-updated', function () {
            this.getItems();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "this" refers to different things depending on when/where it is called. If you want to make it consistent, you'll have to save a reference to the correct this in your own variable. For corrected code, refer answer by @lostbyte.

Comment: If you used vue-resource instead of axios, this wouldn't happen, as vue-resource sets "this" to current component even inside the http callback methods.

Answer (score 0):

It was a general JS mistake. Working code:

### on ItemList.vue Component

```
export default {
data: function () {
    return {
        items: [],
    }
},
methods: {
    getItems: function () {
        axios.get('/dashboard/items')
            .then(response => {
                this.items = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                toastr.error(error, 'Ooops! Something went wrong!');
            })
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.getItems();
    let vm = this;
    EventBus.$on('items-updated', function () {
        vm.getItems();
    });
}
```

}